# Add controls attribute in video tag after state changes

Tags: reactjs, html5-video

I have a video tag in reactJS.

```
      <video {props.flag == true && "controls"}>
        <source src= "/videos/video_tab.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
```

> React is giving me error for `{props.flag == true && "controls"}` is
> not correct syntax

As we know we can get controls in basic html like

```
      <video controls>
        <source src= "/videos/video_tab.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
```

But I want to show controls only when `props.flag == true` by default it is false.
How do I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you first read the [React introduction](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#specifying-attributes-with-jsx).

Props are defined as an attribute and the value is an expression when using curly braces `{}`:

```
      <video controls={props.flag}>
        <source src= "/videos/video_tab.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
```

Comment: Actually I was trying to set `controls=false` from browser inspector. But that was not working.

Comment: From the element inspector in the dev tools, you can only change the attribute which is different from props. The attribute for `HTMLVideoElement#controls` don't need a value. The controls are active when the `controls` attribute is present. If you want to remove the controls, simply remove the `controls` attribute. React does this automagically when using a boolean as value e.g. `controls={props.flag}`.

Comment: The presence of ```controls``` implies a true value.  For the controls to be hidden, the controls attribute must be removed.  ```controls=false``` has an identical response to ```controls=true``` or ```controls=rhinoceros```

Answer (score 1):

I would try `<video controls={props.flag}>`
because `<video something>` is short version of `<video something=true>`